# Changing value of select box in Zurb's Foundation via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm having difficulty changing the value of select box in Zurb's foundation. I'm using the custom forms which just hides the actual select box and uses an unordered list as the select box.
My problem is that the usual method of changing the value of select box doesn't work:

```
$('#selectboxID').val('something')
```

The code above assumes that the value of each of the options in the select box is the same with the text:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
```

I also tried:

```
$($('.dropdown ul li')[1]).addClass('current') 

$($('.dropdown ul li')[0]).removeClass('current') //remove current class from the other one
```

But it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to trigger "change" event after changing selected index.

Example:

```
// Change selected option
$('#selectboxID').val('something');
// Or use selectedIndex: $("#selectboxID")[0].selectedIndex = 0;

// Fire change event
$('#selectboxID').trigger('change');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: do you know if there is a way to update without triggering a change event?  I have a case where user initiated change events perform functions. So I don't want to trigger a change event just to update what the actual select element currently holds.

Comment: in foundation 4 use javascript function: Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($("#selectboxID"))

Comment: @fuzzyalej What did you save it for? You should eat it ASAP, I don't think it keeps for long.

Answer (score 15):

There's also alternative use case when you're binding on change event yourself, you might not want to trigger it. Code to just force a refresh on select:

```
Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select(@jQueryElement, true)
```

where @jQueryElement is a original hidden select.

Comment: This was the way I had to do it for Foundation 4.2.x.  On previous versions firing the change event worked but it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 6):

There have been some modifications to the way that the change event is handled recently in the Foundation code.

You can still achieve what you want using the trigger() method, but you have to add a 'force refresh' flag:

```
$('#selectboxID').trigger('change', true);
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Nice and simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: This saved my life! Thx +100

Answer (score 2):

## If you are using Foundation 3:

Updated to the latest Foundation 3 release.

Setting `selectedIndex`, using JQuery's `val()` or anything which triggers a `change` event is working out of the box.

## If you are using Foundation 4:

This seems to be a regression. As a - *hopefully temporary* - workaround you can force to update the custom select by using the `refresh_custom_selection` method, e.g.:

```
Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_selection($('select'))
```

**Note:** It is `refresh_custom_selection`, not `refresh_custom_select`!

It is not necessary to use the latter (or `trigger('change', true)`) because they both **completely rebuild** the custom select, i.e. they re-copy your select options which involves lots of DOM manipulation and it can slow things down a lot. (Depending on the size of your select options and your other code)

On the other hand `refresh_custom_selection` just updates the displayed value which is a much more lightweight operation.

PS: Instead of `refresh_custom_selection` you could also use

```
$('a.current', $select.next()).text($('option:selected', $select).text());
```

But that code makes assumptions on the generated HTML, so it is better to stick to the provide utility methods